# Transfer money to HSA and then withdraw after paying for expense

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

I have a HSA opened in June with a $1k opening balance. Sometime in August, I had a medical bill totaling $3k and I absent-mindedly paid for it out of my regular checking account.

Assuming I have all my receipts, can I now transfer another $3k into my HSA and then withdraw it back to my regular checking account and have that outflow from my HSA count towards the medical expense? Or am I only allowed to pay for a medical expense if the money directly came from my HSA at the time of payment?

Also, there were some other qualifying medical expenses in April (before I opened the HSA). Again, assuming I have receipts for these, can I adjust that expense against my HSA balance?

Comment: Is your High.Deductible Health Plan (HDHP) single coverage or family coverage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes on the August expenses, No on the April; the expenses must have happened after the HSA was opened.  Also, note that you're limited to (in 2015) $3350 of deposits to the HSA in a single year, so you can only put $2350 more into the HSA.

The IRS form for HSAs looks something like this:

1) How much money did you take from your HSA?
2) How much were your qualified medical expenses?
3) If (1) > (2), give us a bunch of money.

Comment: And if you're 55 or older, you can contribute an additional $1,000 (in 2015) per year.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also found [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/13386/33732) which might be a superset of mine. Apparently, leaving the money in HSA to accrue interest and then claim reimbursements several years later is an acceptable strategy.